# Disable spam protection when generating an Email in Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, rte, powermail

I have enabled `config.spamProtectEmailAddresses = -4` for my Typo3-site.

In a fluid template (that is used for generating the HTML of an email generated by the extension powermail), how can I override this setting to not protect the email adress here?

I have tried (see [parseFunc](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Parsefunc/))

```
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc_email">{text}</f:format.html>
```

but I can't find out which TS-property needs to change.

Or is there a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the TS setting `config.spamProtectEmailAddresses = -4` for specific pages:

```
config.spamProtectEmailAddresses = -4
[globalVar = _GET|tx_powermail_pi1|action = create]
config.spamProtectEmailAddresses = 0
[global]
```

(From https://forge.typo3.org/issues/72983)

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way would be to generate the e-mail link yourself:

```
<a href="mailto:{emailAddress}" title="...">{linkText}</a>
```

Comment: Hm. Yes. But. If possible I would like to keep the RTE so that the user can choose to add several Emailadresses if he chooses to. Then, I could invent a new shortcode [email]asdf@asdf.de[/email] but still this wouldn't be very productive for the site usability ...